# Background Sound Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, forms, audio, vshost32

I am trying to play a song in the background of my windows form aplication.
I tried this:

```
 System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
 sound.Stream = Properties.Resources.K_39_NAAN___Wavin_39_Flag;
 sound.PlayLooping();
```

But when i do this, When my application runs for an x number of  minutes and i get this error:

**vshost32.exe has stopped working**

I cant just use an url because it has to be installed on other computers and work.

Comment: Yes it does play. But after a few minutes i get the error. 

**vshost32.exe has stopped working**

Comment: @user3074355 Try adding `sound.LoadAsync();` before `sound.PlayLooping();`

Comment: What is the scope of your `sound` object? If the lifetime of that object is just a single method you may find it is being cleaned up - try declaring it as a field instead?

Comment: @Tijesunimi Still the same error.

Comment: @Marco Luizinho Still the same error.

Comment: @DanPuzey How do i do this?

Comment: @user3074355: I suspect the code you posted is from a single method. You need to move your declaration of the `sound` variable out of the method so that it has a longer lifetime (perhaps declare it as a field of your main window instead).

Comment: @DanPuzey The code i posted is in the form_load function...

Comment: ... so you need to move your declaration of the sound variable out of the method so that it has a longer lifetime (perhaps declare it as a field of your main window instead).

Comment: @DanPuzey Do you have an example code of how to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you need help creating a field then your needs will be better served by a basic WinForms programming tutorial than by asking questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks ! My problem is fixed.

Declaration above the public form1()

And playlooping insinde the form_load()

Thanks a lot